# How do you hide "Generic USB SD Reader" in nemo file manager when a card is not present?

Tags: linux-mint, sd-card, nemo

I'm running Linux Mint 16. I have a external card reader that has CF, MS, SD, and SM readers in it as well as 3 USB ports. Is there a way to hide the card reader ports from nemo's my computer when there's no cards inserted? I know it's easy to do in windows but i don't know if it's possible in mint.

Comment: What card reader model and driver are you using? It should appear in `lsusb -t` if connected via USB.

Comment: I didn't understand any of the information given from the command `lsusb -t`. You can view it here: [link](http://pastebin.com/56mDuuMd). The device in question is a fairly old nGear USB 2.0 Combo Card Reader that doesn't have a model number or anything on it.

Comment: Possibly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092601/hiding-a-mounted-device-in-nautilus) can help. I don’t have a complete answer, but in my case my external card reader creates /dev/sdd and /dev/sde and a card is inserted as /dev/sde1; so it could be possible (e.g.) to hide /dev/sdd (in fact in my case Nemo doesn’t show any sdd or sde when there is no card, so I don’t have myself this issue).